# Array of bindings with different wrapped values in Swift

Tags: arrays, binding, swiftui, wrapper

I would like a class to contain an array of bindings where the wrapped values are different, however, I am getting the error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Bool>' to expected element type 'Binding<Any>'`. Is there another way to do this than the below code?

```
struct AState {
    @State var boolState:Bool
    @State var intState:Int
}

class Container {
    var bindings:[Binding<Any>]

    init(bindings:[Binding<Any>]) {
        self.bindings = bindings
    }
}

let state = AState(boolState: true, intState: 3)
let container = Container(bindings: [state.$boolState, state.$intState])
```

Comment: What you try to do is concept-breaking and rather would never work, because `@State` has sense and works properly only being declared inside `View` and modified inside `View`.

Comment: @Asperi, the above could be within View structures though could it not? The principle is still the same as far as I can see

Comment: What is the purpose of this array? What are you trying to achieve?